# In oracle database, how can I specify default value for a parameter that is a user defined type?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, default-value, user-defined-types

```
    PACKAGE PKG_DEVICE AS 
     TYPE STR_ASSOC_ARR is table of VARCHAR(255) index by BINARY_INTEGER;
     procedure proc_create_device 
(
  in_deviceid in raw  
, in_devicecert in clob  
, in_status in number
, in_caps in STR_ASSOC_ARR
, in_vals in STR_ASSOC_ARR
);
```

is the stored procedure declaration. I would like to specify a default value for the in_caps and in_vals parameters. Is it possible? I am not able to specify `default null` as it doesn't work. My goal is to not have to pass these two parameters (or pass null) from C# when they are not available. If there is an odp.net way of accomplishing the same, that would work too.
Using oracle db 11g.

Comment: :Are you saying that you don't want to pass the null from the C# side and you want to specify default values only in procedure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to cast NULL as the user defined type. Try this:

```
    PACKAGE PKG_DEVICE AS 
     TYPE STR_ASSOC_ARR is table of VARCHAR(255) index by BINARY_INTEGER;
     procedure proc_create_device 
(
  in_deviceid in raw  
, in_devicecert in clob  
, in_status in number
, in_caps in STR_ASSOC_ARR DEFAULT CAST(NULL AS STR_ASSOC_ARR)
, in_vals in STR_ASSOC_ARR DEFAULT CAST(NULL AS STR_ASSOC_ARR)
);
```

Now you should not have to specify values for in_caps or in_vals. If the values are not passed, they default to NULL values of the STR_ASSOC_ARRAY type.

And of course, you'll need to update the procedure declaration in the package body to correspond to these changes.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass the default value from C# side you can do it using

```
 var sParam1 = new OracleParameter("in_param1_array", 
                                     OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
 sParam1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;

 if (list.Count == 0)
 {
     sParam1.Size = 1;
     sParam1.Value = new string[1] { "" };//Or initialize as default value.
 }
 else
 {
     sParam1.Size = list.Count;
     sParam1.Value = list.ToArray();
 }
 parameters.Add(sParam1);
```

Comment: Why negative point ..Please add the comment.It is relevant to the question asked.